# Can somebody help me in geoemtry to find the new points of the line of refelection for these 3 problems?

Tags: geometry

Okay I can't give you the graph so but basically there are three graphs in front of me that all have a shape such as a rhombus, square or rectangle on it, one shape per graph. At each corner/edge there is a letter like A, B, C or D labeled. Below I have given the line of reflection and the points of which the shape sits on the graph currently in front of me, what I need you to do is help me figure out is what the points are when that shape is reflected. I'd appreciate if you would label you're answers like this for example #1:E'(1,1) and so on and by the way ' means prime if that helps but it's just to differentiate the reflection before and after or something like that along those lines, thanks!

1. line of reflection: y=1; these are the points that originally are for the shape on the graph not reflected: E(-2,0); F(0,0); G(2,-4); H(0,-4)
2. line of reflection: x=-1; these are the points that originally are for the shape on the graph not reflected:J(1,3); K(3,2); I(1,-3); J(3,-2)
3. line of reflection: y=x; these are the points that originally are for the shape on the graph not reflected: R(-3,1); S(-1,1); Q(-3,-2); T(-1,-2)

Comment: Hi, Tamara, welcome to math.stackexchange. While we do offer guidance for homework problems, we usually discourage direct answers like the ones you requested.| For instance, the approach for this kind of problem is to isolate each point, and reflect it; the distance E is from the line $y=1$ is, say, d, and E lies below that line, so go d units above that line directly above E.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply drawing this on graph paper. You can find the reflected points either using a ruler or by counting squares. The same two methods can be used to find the coordinates of the results.